# Em "erva mate", mate é adjetivo?

Tags: adjetivos, classe-gramatical

Notei um falante de inglês querendo simplificar sua fala e disse "chá de erva" ao invés de "chá mate" ou "chá de erva mate". Ele deve ter usado a lógica dos adjetivos após o substantivo do Português (e demais línguas derivadas do Latin), porém acabou ficando vago pois não categorizou de que tipo de erva se tratava o chá.

Qual a classe gramatical da palavra "mate" neste caso? É um adjetivo?

E por que se fala "chá mate" ao invés de "chá de mate"? Na ausênica do "de" não deveria ser "chá-mate"?

Comment: Eu acho que não se classifica como adjetivo, mas não sei dizer ao certo o que seria. Temos também "Carne bovina" -> "Carne de Boi". "Livros Escolares" -> "Livros de Escola"

Comment: no Rio Grande do Sul, se escreve erva-mate. Isso, usada para chimarrão ou mate....

Comment: @Peixoto "erva-mate" faz sentido e se aplicaria ao "chá-mate".

Comment: Os dicionários e a Wikipedia contém as expressões com hífen: 'erva-mate', 'chá-mate' (assim como "erva-cidreira").

Answer (score 4):

O [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) (do Brasil) registra "erva-mate". "Mate", de acordo com a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerba_mate) (em inglês) "deriva do termo quéchua *mati*, que designa o recipiente onde é bebido o chimarrão." "Mate" também é sinônimo de "erva-mate".

Assim sendo, entendo que "erva-mate" é um substantivo composto por justasposição de dois substantivos.

Comment: Muito boa a tua resposta, poderias buscar os textos das referencias que citou e adicionar como citação no teu texto...